# Everywhere I have found men dead of cold and hunger, and that in the midst of the week for lack of flour, all the mills being frozen

Tags: sentence-structure

> As late as April 1789, the comte de Mirabeau observed in the south of France: “every scourge has been unloosed. Everywhere I have found men dead of cold and hunger, and **that** in the midst of the week for lack of flour, all the mills being frozen.”

I want to know whether "that" here is grammatical ?

https://time.com/6107671/french-revolution-history-climate/

Comment: The entire paragraph is a poor translation. [...] and that in the middle of the week for lack of flour, all the mills had stopped running."

Comment: Thank you. I wonder is it "parallel structure", but then it makes no sense for "that" to be here.

Comment: Generally, in old texts or texts like these parallelism does not matter. That is only for modern writing in journalism or technical writing. Fyi, there is a that in the first (implied): Everywhere I have found [that] men [are] dead of cold and hunger, So, it might just be a translation thing. Who knows....:)

Comment: I would interpret **that** as referring to the finding of the dead people, as though he thought it less likely to happen in the middle of the week (I'm not sure why he should think so).

Comment: That makes sense too ...

Comment: @Lambie  - Surely the lack of flour was _because_ the (water) mills were frozen?

Comment: @KateBunting, Thank you very much. Now I got an answer : https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and%20that

Comment: @KateBunting I was thinking flour mills, all dry. Where the millstone is activated by horses or mules.

Comment: @Lambie - Well, of course it's flour mills! They were usually powered by wind or water. I can't access the Time article, but it's apparently about cold climate causing starvation, so why would _frozen_ not be intended literally?

Comment: @KateBunting I just have never heard of a mill being frozen per se, so, in any event, it ain't well **translated**. And by the way, in dry countries like Spain, mills used mules or oxen or the wind. But I take your point.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the highly questionable syntax and vocabulary of a very old and very poor quality translation.